# os.walk on non C drive directory

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.walk

I know there are several posts that touch on this, but I haven't found one that works for me yet.  I need to create a list of files with an .mxd extension by searching an entire mapped directory.  I used this code and it works:

```
    import os
    file_list = []
    for (paths, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".mxd"):
                file_list.append(os.path.join(paths, file))
```

However, it only works on the C drive.  I need to be able to search for these files on a mapped drive of my choosing.  Here's the script I'm using, but it doesn't work.  I know there is an mxd file in the subdirectory of this drive, but it isn't being reported in the file list.  In fact, the file list is totally empty, and it shouldn't be.

```
    import os
    path = r"U:/TEST/"
    filenamelist = []
    for files in os.walk(path):
         if file.endswith(".mxd"):
            filenamelist.append(files)
```

Does someone see anything wrong in my second block of code that would provent it from iterated through subdirectories at the given path and reporting back files with an .mxd extension?

Answer (score 1):

[os.walk(path)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) yields a 3-tuple which is commonly unpacked as `root, dirs, files`. So instead of

```
for files in os.walk(path):
    ...
```

use

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".mxd"):
            filenamelist.append(filename)
```

Comment: unutbu, this works.  But when I specify a path, such as r'U:\\', the result lists path with four backslashes after the U drive letter and two backslashes after each folder.  Is there a way to clean this up a bit. My script needs to crawl starting from the root of the drive.

Comment: Well...I guess ArcGIS has no problem with four backslashes after the drive letter.  Looks weird, but it works.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What you are seeing are escape sequence. `'\\'` is a Python `str` representing *one* backslash. See the ["String literals"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) doc page.

Answer (score 1):

> Does someone see anything wrong in my second block of code that would provent it from iterated through subdirectories at the given path and reporting back files with an .mxd extension?

Yes. Compare and contrast your two loops:

```
for (paths, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mxd"):
            file_list.append(os.path.join(paths, file))

for files in os.walk(path):
     if file.endswith(".mxd"):
        filenamelist.append(files)
```

You're trying to do the exact same thing, but not using even remotely the same code.

In the first one, you loop over the `walk`, storing each tuple in `(paths, dirs, files)`, then loop over `files`.

In the second one, you loop over the `walk`, storing each tuple in `files`, don't loop over anything, and then just use some variable named `file` left over from some earlier code.

And then, even if that part worked, you end up appending `files` (which, remember, is a tuple of three lists) rather than `file`—or, probably better, `os.path.join(paths, file)`—to the list.

Just make the second one look like the first. Or, better, put it in a function and call it twice, instead of copying and pasting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final script that worked for crawling on a drive root other than C:

```
import os
file_list = []
path = r'U:\\'
for (dirpath, subdirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mxd"):
            file_list.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```